Erro Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppCenterReactNative
I have the following errors when running the build in xcode.
My React Native 0.72.6 project
XCode 15.4
appcenter 5.0.1
Before it worked correctly, I needed to build the project again and it presented these errors. How to solve?
It follows the build process and when you open Metro to install the app these errors appear. I followed all the appcenter documentation but it doesn't work.
I don't have anything in Podfile to handle this (it doesn't ask for it in the documentation).


It was fixed by implementing the:
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = "arm64"
      end
    end```
